# Application using Multi-AZ RDS Sql*Server on Failover

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

If we have an application (i.e. a WCMS) using a SQL*Server Multi-AZ RDS and the server fails over, do we need to reset the connection strings or will we just a few timeouts for a period of time until the service is reconfigured to point at the standby replica ?

Im assuming unlike standard SQL*Server database mirroring connection strings you cant configure a primary and secondary server as AWS just provides the DNS entry and fails over itself ?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have to reset the connection string just select the reboot with connection string option, and the entire SQL Server instance will fail over as an atomic unit to the standby host.

Check this blog https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rds-for-sql-server-with-multi-az/

Comment: Thanks - so how would that look to an application? Wouldn't it timeout for the several minutes this is happening ?

Comment: The issue is AWS does not give you fix timings for how long it will take. But you can try to test it out how much time it takes for your application by forcing a failover so you will have an approx idea of the timings.